# HQL query multiple record result from list of multiple pair values

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I am having a difficult time finding a way to request a list of records, where the criteria is a list of pairs of values.  Here is the general structure of my table.

```
| ID  |  PROP1  |  PROP2  |  PROP3  |
-------------------------------------
|  1  |   AAA   |   11    |  VAL1   |
-------------------------------------
|  2  |   BBB   |   22    |  VAL2   |
-------------------------------------
|  3  |   CCC   |   33    |  VAL3   |
-------------------------------------
```

I need to be able to select all PROP3 values from a list where my criteria looks like this:

```
[ [prop1:'AAA',prop2:'11'], [prop1:'BBB',prop2:'22' ] ]
```

That result would be: ['VAL1','VAL2']

I have done queries with an "IN" condition, and I have done queries with multiple criteria, but I am completely stumped on putting them together in HQL.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `select ent.PROP3 from entity ent where (ent.PROP1 = 'AAA' and ent.PROP2 = '11') or (ent.PROP1 = 'BBB' and ent.PROP2 = '22')`

Comment: I was looking for a more dynamic approach so that the list could be any length and any sets of values, and I could still use a @Query annotation on my method to pass the list of criteria to.

Comment: Do you have a SQL (not hql) already doing this?